# js join("\n") not start at new line

Tags: javascript, antd

I am using an Ant Design table, and this is one of my columns. I would like to show every name on a new line, and I'm using "\n" but it's not working - it only adds spaces, it doesn't start the second name at the new line.

```
{
    title: "Borrower Name",
    width: 150,
    dataIndex: "borrower",
    render: (record) => record.map((a) => a.name).join("\n"),
}
```

Comment: HTML uses `<br/>` instead.

Comment: using console.log it should work: `console.log(["a", "b"].join("\n"))`

Comment: @ 
Martin Zeitler
 I tried join(<br/>) and join("<br/>"）,but both not working

Comment: @
valerii15298 console.log is working ,but I want to show them in the column

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using HTML tag (i have used paragraph tag, you can use br tag), this will display all the names on new line.

```
{
  title: 'Borrower Name',
  width: 150,
  dataIndex: 'borrower',
  render: (record) => record.map((a) => <p>{a.name}</p>),
},
```

Or

```
{
  title: 'Borrower Name',
  width: 150,
  dataIndex: 'borrower',
  render: (record) => record.map((a) => <>{a.name}<br/></>),
},
```

Answer (score -1):

@Help
*I tried join(<br/>) and join("<br/>"）,but both not working;*

join(<br/>) will give error
join("<br/>") will consider this as separator

```
(method) Array<string>.join(separator?: string | undefined): string
Adds all the elements of an array into a string, separated by the specified separator string.
@param separator — A string used to separate one element of the array from the next in the resulting string. If omitted, the array elements are separated with a comma.
```

You can map over the record and add a <br/> tag like this:

```
render: (_: any, row: any) =>['a', 'b'].map((item) => (<>{item}<br /></>))
```

Answer (score -2):

map() function should return something,
Should be like this:

```
render: (record) => record.map(a => {return a.name}).join("\n")
```

Comment: it  shows this error, Uncaught TypeError: a.name.join is not a function

Comment: I edited the answer, look to the answer again and tell me what will happen. It should work now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ Anonymous Programmer now it not showing error but not working still not start at the new line